# A prohibition on the disable of brackets in sympy

Tags: sympy

There is the following simple problem:

```
integrate((x-2)^3,x)
```

Instead of just giving a simple answer:

```
(x-2)^4/4
```

Sympy spreads out on an endless tape

```
x^4/4-2*x^3+6*x^2-8*x
```

It can be trained to give an easy answer, as `(x-2)^4/4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "manual" integration method:

```
In [24]: integrate((x-2)**3,x, manual=True)
Out[24]: 
       4
(x - 2) 
────────
   4
```